# DELETE specific dates in DB

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgresql, how do I delete all records that contain part of a date, for example... DELETE FROM table WHERE startdate = '01-01', but I need to delete with this date, no matter what year is recorded to DB... 2019-01-01 or 2020-01-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
DELETE FROM table
    WHERE TO_CHAR(startdate, 'MM-DD') = '01-01';
```

Or, extract the month and day explicitly:

```
    WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM startdate) = 1 AND
          EXTRACT(DAY FROM startdate) = 1;
```